# async await что я делаю не так?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, область-видимости, инкапсуляция

```
let st = async function ()  {
  try {
  
    let allow = await {
      dir1: ["IN"],
      dir2: ["ES","KE"],
      dir3: ["GT","PE"]
    }
    let data = await []

    await Object.keys(allow).forEach( async dirName => {

      const dir = await dirName

      await allow[dir].forEach( async geo => {
        
        // let select = await []


        return await data.push({
          test: 'test'
        })
      
      })


    })

    
    await console.log(data)
  
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
st()
```

почему когда я сориентирую строчку `// let select = await []`
то `data` становится пустой и за **await** ?

Answer (score 2):

await ставится перед асинхронными функциями и промисами.
Ставить его перед синхронным кодом как минимум бесполезно

читайте в источнике:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Answer (score 1):

await - специальный синтаксис для работы с **промисами**, который работает только в асинхронных функциях.

```js
async function foo() {

  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("End"), 1000)
  });

  const result = await promise; // Ждём выполнение промиса
  console.log(result);
}

foo();
```